# MySQL to HQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

How should I convert this MySQL query to HQL to retrieve some data I need?

```
SELECT pu.url, count(sen.content) 
FROM Sentence sen JOIN ProcessedUrl pu 
ON sen.PROCESSED_URL_ID=pu.url_id 
GROUP BY pu.url ORDER BY 2;
```

In my code there is POJO ProcessedUrl which have id/url/date/set(of Sentence) fields mapped. I wanted to do something like:

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

List<ProcessedUrl> result = session.createQuery("proper HQL query", ProcessedUrl.class).getResultList();

transaction.commit();
session.close();
return result;
```

and then iterate over this result to print `result.getUrl()` & `result.getSentences().size()` for each url.

I know my query should return fields which are inside `ProcessedUrl` then how I can return some grouped query and retrieve data from it that is not kept directly inside the table? Like this `count()` for every url?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't want a List<ProcessedUrl> as result. You want a List<Object[]>, where each array would have a url as its first element, and a count as its second element. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions

Comment: That helped :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out right HQL query so no need help anymore.

```
List<Object[]> result = session.createQuery("select pu.url, count(sen.content)"
        + " FROM ProcessedUrl pu"
        + " JOIN pu.sentences sen "
        + " GROUP BY pu.url "
        + " ORDER BY 2", Object[].class).getResultList();
```